# How to recover the key password into a keystore?

Tags: android, keystore, brute-force

I have a keystore with two keys. I remember the keystore password but I can't remember the exact password of the key with alias B. I remeber the start of the password but not the end of it. Any idea? Do you know any software to recover it?

I read some questions and use some applications but they only recover the keystore password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By design this should be non-recoverable. If you have a partial password (and can make some guesses on the remaining) your best option is attempting to brute force it.

Googling for this will yield you some results for specific apps (my quick search pulled up results for TrueCrypt, winrar, etc). Not sure what the details of the Android keystore/key encryption are, but I suspect you can find something already built or adaptable. Depending on how much of the password you remember, this will be more or less achievable... Noting you have searched and tried some things - I am guessing you will need to keep looking and use something adaptable :)

Comment: I managed to recover the password with a little brute force. The point of all was: ````keytool -keypasswd -alias "alias" -keystore .keystore -storepass storepass -keypass oldpass -new asdfgh````

Comment: Would be kind enough to share the script you wrote for brute-forcing? I am in the same boat and struggling to recover my alias password.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you will be able to do this.  That is kind of the point of using a keystore for security.

You cannot deploy the same app, signed with a different key to the Play store, so it is important you keep your current keystore info available.

Comment: Given his specific situation a brute force attack could be quite possible. I would agree with your if he did not have a partial password.

Comment: Yup, but there is no way he will be able to recover the password using software.  He will need to somehow "guess" the password (using brute force, or good guessing).

Answer (score 0):

There are one way to clone it and create new alias. I recovered it with that way and saved my application and published new versions of my app.

Comment: Please provide more detail on how you did this.

Comment: Please provide more details

Comment: Please provide the solution